# Devexpress how to delete space in gauge control?

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress, gauge

I've use DevExpress Gauge control in Winforms. And I want to delete unused space between border and ArcScaleBackgroundLayerComponent. 
[image]
How make this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As described in the Coordinate System, circular gauges have relative width and height equal to 250. This means that they always have a rectangle shape when the AutoLayout feature is enabled. 
 So, to accomplish your task, you can change the size of all elements to stretch them to fill the entire rectangle. However, in this case, the Gauge will look not proportional: it will be stretched to the top.

If previous solution is not suitable for you, it is necessary to disable the AutoLayout feature.

Comment: Gauge control inside tablelayoutpanel cell and Dock = Fill, and AutoLayout is false.

Comment: Had referred some discussion on dev express community when i was facing this issue...
Refer this link...
http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/p/Q235939.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can use zero values of the [GaugeControl.LaoutPadding](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraGaugesWinGaugeControlBase_LayoutPaddingtopic) property when the [GaugeControl.AutoLayout](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraGaugesWinGaugeControlBase_AutoLayouttopic) property is set to true or specify the gauge [Bounds](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#CoreLibraries/DevExpressXtraGaugesCoreModelBaseGauge_Boundstopic) property itself within the GaugeControl.